# retrieve values in selected row of gridview from wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new with WPF.

I am trying to retireve values of selected row of gridview in respected text boxes.

In windows application, i use to do it like:

```
txtPartyCode=gv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

But i am confused, how to do it with WPF?

I tried:

```
txtPartyCode.Text=gvCust.SelectedItem[0]
```

but, red tooltip is appearing below code : `can not apply index with [] to an expression of type object.`

Please help me. How to do it with WPF?

Comment: First of all, there is no *normal windows application*. I'm assuming that you're talking of Winforms. Did you think about using `Binding`?

Comment: what is the type of  gv.ItemsSource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here i am confused what is your data type. which you are passing to the ItemsSource property of datagrid.

if you are usnig DataTable and passing it to datagrid then the below code will work for you.

```
void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {                   
            DataRowView rowview = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (rowview != null)
            {
             textbox1.Text=  rowview.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }            
        }
```

and if you are using Typed object for the itemsSource property of DataGrid e.g List of Employees. then here what you can do.

```
 Employee emp  = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Employee
if(emp !=null)
{
textBox1.Text =  emp.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void YourGridName_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {               
          string fc = null;                   
          foreach (var item in e.AddedCells)
           {                        
            fc =((System.Data.DataRowView(item.Item)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
           }
         }
```

Comment: on row selection this event will get fired?

Comment: yes on your datagrid desginer go do properties -events and add the event

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataRowView' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context E:\WPFTuts\NewSoftWCF\NewSoftWCF\MainWindow.xaml.cs 103 19 NewSoftWCF

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataRow' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context E:\WPFTuts\NewSoftWCF\NewSoftWCF\MainWindow.xaml.cs 103 24 NewSoftWCF

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding a handler for the DataGrid SelectionChanged Event, as follows:

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       DataRowView rowview = gv.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
       string textNeeded = rowview.Row[0].ToString();
}
```